# Оптимизация запроса между двумя разными таблицами

Tags: mysql, opencart

Здравствуйте уважаемые!
Opencart, таблицы oc_product_description и oc_url_alias. В первой описание товаров (product_id, name и т.д.) во второй алиасы для ЧПУ url (url_alias_id, query, keyword). Связей между таблицами нет, значение query = "product_id=xxx", значение keyword = "nazvanie-tovara-v-translite".
Есть такой запрос:

```
select distinct product_id 
from oc_product_description 
where product_id not in (select substring(query,12) 
                         from oc_url_alias 
                         where query like 'product_id%') 
  and not name=''
```

Выполнение запроса занимает примерно 9-15 секунд, вопрос в том, возможно ли как то оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: *возможно ли как то оптимизировать запрос?* Переписать на LEFT JOIN.  Создать необходимые для выполнения запроса индексы.

Comment: Предполагался такой вариант, но меня интересует вариант без вмешательство в структуру таблиц.

Comment: Тогда только первый совет.

Comment: Индексы не меняют структуру таблицы. вся система будет работать с ними как и раньше, только быстрее (если по правильным полям сделаны)

Comment: Индексы уже проставлены в таблицах, я имел ввиду добавление еще одного столбца для связи с первой таблицей.

Comment: я может чего-то пропустил, вы делали explain этого запроса?